# Filter search in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm about writing code for searching result by inserting filter input.

My problem is :

I'm getting only one object in a list (for example, my actual database contains 2 objects for the wanted search, but it is displaying only one)

So, I want to return list of objects that I'm looking for by inserting data in Arg and display the real data of what I'm looking for.

This is the class of input search:

```
public class Argument
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public int ExamId { get; set; }
}
```

And this is method in service layer:

```
public IQueryable<Result> GetSByArg(Argument arg)
{
    var isTestIdNull = string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg.TestId.ToString());
    var isExamIdNull = string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg.ExamId.ToString());

    var fetch = (from x in _dbContext.Repo
                 where (true)
                    && (isTestIdNull|| x.TestId.Equals(arg.TestId))
                    && (isExamIdNull || x.isExamIdNull.Equals(arg.isExamIdNull ))
                 select x);

    return fetch;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested with your code. They are working fine.

I only modify the `IQueryable<T>` and `x.isExamIdNull.Equals(arg.isExamIdNull )` part.

```
        public IQueryable<Repo> GetSByArg(Argument arg)
        {
            var isTestIdNull = string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg.TestId.ToString());
            var isExamIdNull = string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg.ExamId.ToString());

            var fetch = (from x in _dbContext.Repo
                         where (true)
                            && (isTestIdNull || x.TestId.Equals(arg.TestId))
                            && (isExamIdNull || x.ExamId.Equals(arg.ExamId))
                         select x);

            return fetch;
        }
```

Database
[image]
Request:

```
{
  "testId": 11,
  "examId": 12
}
```

Output
[image]

Maybe you need check the data.

Comment: yes I had an issue in my arg class , has another attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly use where method on your DbSet like:

```
var result = await _dbContext.Repo.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg.TestId.ToString()) ||
                                                                section.Title.Equals(arg.TestId.ToString())
                                                                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg.ExamId.ToString()) ||
                                                                section.Title.Equals(arg.ExamId.ToString()))
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Hello Sir same problem displaying only one object in a list